# Advancing an index forward and reverse continually, without a loop

Tags: java

I'm working on a project using an ArrayList where I need to advance an index only once, but when it gets to the last index, I need it to go backwards to the 0 index, and start over again. This would be simple enough if I could use a loop, but I need it to only advance one index forward (or backward) when the method is called. 
Anyone have some advice on how to pull this off?

I apologize for the lack of information. I'm making an arraylist of boolean objects, and what im trying to do is make it so that when my method is called, I make the next index true (and the others false), my issue is getting it to stop at the last index, and go in reverse.

For example, think a larson scanner. My issue is that, while this is simple with a loop, I need it to only advance one index when the method is called, not continually advance.

true false false false

false true false false

false false true false

false false false true

false false true false

false true false false

etc

### Sorry for the confusion

Comment: What kind of object are you iterating over?

Comment: You are looking for while loops, aren't you? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: HOW ABOUT .. a *linked list* ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where my answer fails in comparison to your question.

Comment: It doesn't, I made the correction for the clarification to the others. Your answer did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the array is a field:

```
Object[] arr;
boolean backwards; //init: false
int current; //init: 0

public Object getNextObject() {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array cannot be empty!");
    }
    int index;
    if (backwards) {
        index = --current;
        if (index <= 0) {
            backwards = false;
            index = 0;
        }
    } else {
        index = ++current;
        if (index >= arr.length) {
            backwards = true;
            index = arr.length - 1;
        }
    }
    Object back = arr[index];
    current = index;
    return back;
}
```

This would also essentially apply to any data structure you worked with (Swapping `.length` with `.size()`, etc)

Comment: Close, you probably need to keep track of direction, update the index accordingly and change direction at either ends of the array

Comment: @michel-slm Aha, my mistake! A small misread on the question, I'll update